# Counting cells in Excel while comparing to the value of the previously counted cell

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a way, without writing VBA code, to count the number of cells, containing date and time, that are a full day apart while not counting the cells in between.

Example:
I have rows with the following values:

```
2018-03-19 18:33
2018-03-30 08:21
2018-03-30 11:21
2018-04-01 06:51
2018-04-01 08:17
2018-04-01 15:34
```

I want to get the number of cells that correspond to my conditions. In that case, the result I would like is 3, because the first cell and second cell are at least a day apart and the only value after, that is a full day following the second cell is the fourth cell.

To sum it up, I always need to go 24h from the last "counted" cell and count that cell etc.

I've found a way to do it using the SMALL function and outputting the results to multiple columns. Basically I start by getting the smallest date, then reference this value using another SMALL function but adding 1 to the previous value. But that way gives me the actual date and requires a different column for each iteration when in reality all a need is a count.

I also tried using SUMPRODUCT and comparing the range to an offset version of itself, but that compares the value to the last one in the array rather than the last "found" value.

I'm looking for suggestions and pointers on which Excel function to use. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming your dates are in column `A` is `=IF(A2-A1>1,ROW(),"")` what you're looking for?

Comment: In your statement you say the result should be 3. But what I see it appears that cell 2 is >1d than cell 1, Cell 4 is >1d from cell 2, and none >1d than cell 4. But cell 4 is also >1d than cell 3. Since it is counted, use cell 5 as >1d than cell 3 so your count is 3? This seems a bit confusing. Please update the picture to include highlights or helpers to show what exactly you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, the line: "that is a full day following the second cell is the fifth cell" should have been: "that is a full day following the second cell is the fourth cell", since march has 31 days. (The post was edited to reflect this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a way of doing it without a helper column. If a helper column can be used, you could do it like this:

(1) Set B2 to 1.

(2) Copy this formula down from B3:

```
=IF(A3-INDEX(A:A,MATCH(2,B$1:B2))>=1,1,"")
```

Then just count up the 1's in B3 onwards.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a workable solution, I'll definitely be giving it a try. Thanks a lot!